# How to fetch Object type environment variable?

Tags: node.js, express, configuration, environment-variables

Currently I have environment variables set in this way in my nodejs application:

`

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  process.env.LOGGER_LEVEL = 'silly';
  process.env.DB = 'db-v2-staging';
  process.env.DB_URI = 'localhost';
  process.env.SOME_FLAG = true;
  process.env.SOME_API_KEY = 'y43e6fgccdxfgvH4JR-KiUWkIvJeWiw';
  process.env.SftpServer = {
    host: '111.11.11.11',
    port: 22,
    username: 'johndoe',
    password: 'johndoe',
    input: './input_clone_test',
    output: './output_clone_test',
  };
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  process.env.LOGGER_LEVEL = 'silly';
  process.env.DB = 'db-v2-staging';
  process.env.DB_URI = 'localhost';
  process.env.SOME_FLAG = true;
  process.env.SOME_API_KEY = 'y43e6fgccdxfgvH4JR-KiUWkIvJeWiw';
  process.env.SftpServer = {
    host: '111.11.11.11',
    port: 22,
    username: 'johndoe',
    password: 'johndoe',
    input: './input_test',
    output: './output_test',
  };
}
```

`Problem i face is when i try to access`process.env.SftpServer`it gives me **"[object Object]"** as output, even if i go with`JSON.stringify(process.env.SftpServer)` it gives me **""[object Object]""** . Need to figure out the solution, please suggest the solution if possible without using third party module for env variable management.

Answer (score 1):

ENV variables are OS dependent thing. They don't support JS Object Notation.
The solution is set it up as a string and then do a JSON parse while getting.

```
process.env.SftpServer  = `{
  "host": "111.11.11.11",
  "port": 22, "username": "johndoe", 
  "password": "johndoe", 
  "input": "./input_clone_test", 
  "output": "./output_clone_test"
}`;


console.log(JSON.parse(process.env.SftpServer ))
```